# DOM Elements (Nodes)

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm new in JS, I tried to write a simple for loop. but it doesn't work.
I want make a loop to write `this is the paragraph 1, this is the paragraph 2, ...`

This is my code :

```
<body>

    <button id="makeP">Make yours paragraphs</button>

    <div id="block">
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("makeP").onclick = makeParagraph;

        function makeParagraph() {
            var text = "this is the paragraph ";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
                para.appendChild(node);
                var element = document.getElementById("block");
                element.appendChild(para);
            }
        }


    </script>

</body>
```

I try with `document.write()` but after the click on button I have all line with the text, but the button is delete;

I try :

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById("makeP").onclick = makeParagraph;

        function makeParagraph() {
            var text = "this is the paragraph ";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
                para.appendChild(node);
                var element = document.getElementById("block");
                element.appendChild(para);
            }
        }


    </script>
```

It works but I don't know how to use `br` to distinguish the different lines after every loop.

Comment: Your first code example works just fine for me. The button is not deleted and everything appears to work just fine.  I used chrome.  What browser are you in?  Have you looked at the console in developer tools?

Comment: It is working in firefox

Comment: **Phaelax** is right. Your first example seems fine. Heres the working codesandbox of that code: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-field-2m3sq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code where a **'hr'** tag is created  on every click.

**EDITED**

Now with the hr tag, it will have a new background-color on every click.

```js
 document.getElementById("makeP").onclick = makeParagraph;

        function makeParagraph() {
          //For coloring
          const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

          //creating a wrapper
          wrapper = document.createElement("div");
          wrapper.classList.add("color");
          wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
          document.getElementById("block").appendChild(wrapper);

          var text = "this is the paragraph ";
          let i;
          for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
            para.appendChild(node);
            wrapper.appendChild(para);
          }

          wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      <button id="makeP">Make yours paragraphs</button>

      <div id="block"></div>

    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

*With while and do-while loops*

```
         //Do while loop

          do{
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
            para.appendChild(node);
            wrapper.appendChild(para);

            i++;
          }while (i<11);



         /*  

         //While loop
          while (i<11){
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
            para.appendChild(node);
            wrapper.appendChild(para);

            i++;
          } 
          */



          //For Loop
          /* for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
            para.appendChild(node);
            wrapper.appendChild(para);
          } */
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: @SevenDays, Welcome. Please check now. I hv edited the code.

Comment: Hi
I have try the new code and it is perfect, so, if i want only 10 paragraphs, i can put the script in a while or do while loop?

Comment: @SevenDays, yes you can..shoiuld i add code snippet for that?..let me know..

Comment: @SevenDays,refer the link.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: yes, i try to put "while" before the  `for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {` but it doesn't work

Comment: @SevenDays,i have added the code.. Please check now. if it helps....i would be happier

Comment: Yes i check, so... i prefer the loop do while but  the result is _this is the paragraph undefined_ i fix it.
Thank you so much @tedd

Comment: @SevenDays, i am gald that i was able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that on each click of a button you're running the whole loop - each time you press the button, it runs from beginning to end. I assume you'd like to print one paragraph at a time while incrementing the counter at the same time by one.

You could make use of a callback function that uses an external variable to know what is the consecutive paragraph number like so:

```
let i = 1;
document.getElementById("makeP").onclick = () => {
    if (10 >= i) { // limit the number of paragraphs to 10
        return;
    }
    const text = "this is the paragraph ";
    const para = document.createElement("p");
    const node = document.createTextNode(text + i);
    para.appendChild(node);
    const element = document.getElementById("block");
    element.appendChild(para);
    ++i;
}
```

It's also good practice to declare tokens whose value would not change in your program as constants. Each paragraph should already be on its own line since a an html paragraph displays as a block in a browser so will occupy the whole width of its parent container (here the whole document).

Hope that helps, good luck with learning JS!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have a question, to limit the number of paragraphs to 10 do I have to put all the code in a while?

Comment: Hi @SevenDays, you can just break out of the callback earlier. I've just edited the code in the answer.